# setApplicationContext() of ApplicationContextAware is not calling while making rest call

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, jersey-2.0

I have implemented the **ApplicationContextAware** in base class and extended the base class to web service resource class. Initially when the server is starting then `setApplicationContext()` of BaseEndPoint class is called , but after start up When I make the rest call to resource class then `setApplicationContext()`  of base class is not calling because of which application context object is set to  null . Due to which **NULL Pointer Exception** is coming.

I am not able to figure out why setApplicationContext is not calling of **BaseEndPoint** class while making rest call?

Error

```
 Oct 23, 2015 1:13:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/ornacms] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.orna.common.web.services.catalog.endpoint.BaseEndpoint.findAllCategories(BaseEndpoint.java:75)
    at com.orna.api.endpoint.catalog.CatalogResource.findAllCategories(CatalogResource.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

BaseEndPoint class in defined in different module

```
public abstract class BaseEndpoint implements ApplicationContextAware {

@Autowired
protected CatalogItemService catalogService;


public CatalogItemService getCatalogService() {
    return catalogService;
}

public void setCatalogService(CatalogItemService catalogService) {
    this.catalogService = catalogService;
}

private ApplicationContext context;

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    this.context = applicationContext;

}

public Categories findAllCategories(HttpServletRequest request,
        String name, int limit, int offset) {
    List<Category> categories;
    if (name != null) {
        categories = catalogService.findCategoriesByName(name, limit,
                offset);
    } else {
        categories = catalogService.findAllCategories(limit, offset);
    }
    Categories bind= (CategoriesWrapper) context
            .getBean(CategoriesWrapper.class.getName());
    bind.wrapObject(categories, request);
    return bind;
}
```

This is the Actual Resource class defined in web module

```
package com.orna.api.endpoint.catalog;

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Path("/catalog")
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class CatalogResource extends BaseEndpoint {

    @Override
    @GET
    public CategoriesWrapper findAllCategories(
            @QueryParam("name") String name,
            @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue("10") int limit,
            @QueryParam("offset") @DefaultValue("0") int offset) {
        System.out.println("name=" + name + " " + "limit=" + limit + " "
                + "offset=" + offset);
        return super.findAllCategories(request, name, limit, offset);
    }

    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID">

    <display-name>Ornament WebApp</display-name>
    <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>jsp/categoryList.jsp</welcome-file> 
        </welcome-file-list> -->



    <!-- enable configured logging -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                classpath:applicationContext-persistence.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Initialize spring mvc -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

            <param-value>
                        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-rest-api.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.orna.api.endpoint.catalog</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

applicationContext-rest-api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Scan for custom REST endpoints -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.orna.api.endpoint.catalog" /> 

    </beans>
```

Comment: `ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext` is not supposed to be called on each call to the implementation. It will only be called once the ApplicationContext is successfully created (on server startup). Is `CatalogResource` under `com.orna.api.endpoint.catalog`?

Comment: @onepotato yes when I start the the server I got the setApplicationContext() called.  But after server start up when I make the request to  through rest my context is becoming null I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Ofcourse it won't... You have a JAX-RS bean (jersey) which isn't managed by Spring so how should spring be able to inject the context. You currently have 2 instances, one spring and one jersey managed instance. The spring one does have a reference to other doesn't. When using Jersey make sure you have the Spring integration setup correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please give the references so that I can set up the jersey2.x and spring4.x  correctly

Comment: That is all explained in the jersey reference guide. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html